# LibreOffice Calc - more than million (empty) rows

Tags: scrolling, libreoffice-calc

I've pasted the data from an outer source into LibreOffice Calc. There are ~3000 legit rows and around a million empty after. This makes problems with vertical scrollbar because it is very small now and I can't scroll down or up because it's so sensitive.

I think I need to somehow delete those empty rows or hide them, but how?

Comment: What's your external source and why can't you get just the 3000 good rows?

Comment: I did. I don't know where all the other empty rows came from. I think after applying a border for whole column instead of specific cells but I'm not sure.

Comment: and now .. what is the external source? can you modify the output of that source? is working with .csv files an option (coz text-modifying tools work on text-only files)

Comment: Let's put it this way: I have an .ods file which contains all this info. The source of the original data is gone. I need to fix it within Calc, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest fix is cut & paste the array of data to a new sheet, and don't format entire rows/columns again.

That was an Excel 1.0 bug too that lasted for many generations.

Use the Shift + [end] +[arrow] or [ctrl]+[shift] + [arrow down] to highlight to the end of the array then in across with [shift] + [arrow] to mark the area or any other means (goto special ...)

Answer (score 0):

If your data permits it, you could paste the whole thing into a text editor like Notepad++.  That should clean up your extra rows pretty easily or at least identify where the extra 997 000 rows are coming from.  You may lose some column markers but that can be fixed after working out where the other rows come from.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but my source is not available anymore. I want to fix this within Calc.

Comment: If you save the data from Calc as a .csv, you can then open it in a text editor, follow Green's suggestion, then open it in Calc again and save it as an .ods.

Comment: That sounds good SaintWacko.  Seconded. I'm frankly very surprised that Calc will even open 1M rows.  Any non trivial amount of data per row could easily push the total table size into the tens or hundreds of megabytes.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue with your data but with Libre Office. I copied a fewer than 100 rows by 15 columns from an existing xls into a new sheet and the new sheet then contained 1,048,576 rows. This needs a ticket over at Libre Office as the solution suggested above may very well fall foul of the same issue again.